# tkcalendar takes a lot of time to load when I try to add more than 10 calendar widgets

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkcalendar

Hi I have a code where I have a button which adds calender widgets, when I add more than 10 or 11 widgets, the program lags a lot. It takes a lot of time to insert the widget, could someone please help me how to circumvent this issue ?

```
from tkinter import Button, Tk
from tkcalendar import  DateEntry

root = Tk()
Date = []

def Add():
    Date.append({})
    n = len(Date)-1
    Date[n]= DateEntry(root)
    Date[n].grid(row=n+1, column=0)
    print (n)

button = Button(root, text='Add', command=Add).grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Comment: well you do not have a `mainloop()` in your example.

Comment: Please don't ask two questions at once. Either ask about multiple calendar widgets or ask about using pyinstaller, but not both in the same question.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Noted.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I have the same issue?

Comment: I used a different datepicker at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/580725-tkinter-datepicker-like-the-jquery-ui-datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

When I add `root.mainloop()` to the end of your example the code runs fine.

Make sure you have the mainloop in your code before you compile as it is required.

Comment: The code runs fine, however, after adding 10 calendar widgets, adding anymore takes a lot of time. Please click the add button 10 or 12 times to see the difference. And moreover, when I convert it to an exe, and click the add button it says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'babel.numbers'.

Comment: I added 30 and it ran fine. Maybe your PC is not very powerful? Or you are running on a VM with limited resources?

Comment: absolutely not, I am not running it on a VM. I ran this code on a workstation with multiple processors at my work and I ran it in my home with i7, still it does not run smoothly. Could you please tell me what type of a machine you are running this on ?

Comment: My work PC is windows 7 i7-6700 with 8gb ram. No issues after adding many widgets.

Comment: I am using Windows 10, do you think it could be an issue ?

Comment: It really should not be. I can test it when I get home on my home PC/Windows 10

Comment: Sadly, the issue persists, how did it go with the home PC ?

Comment: I wont be home for another 4 hours. I can check my windows 10 pc then.